# How to find longest substring using Regular Expression in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, regex, sequence

I have the following array:

```
$array = array("6", "66", "67", "68", "69", "697", "698", "699");
```

I have the following strings:

```
"69212345", "6209876544", "697986546"
```

I want to find the array element which matches longest part from beginning of the string, i.e.

- for "69212345" array value "69" will be selected.
- for "6209876544" array value "6" will be selected.
- for "697986546" array value "697" will be selected.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Where are you stuck with achieving this goal?

Comment: I can't understand how to do it... don't want to loop through the array elements because my array is very long... Is it possible to find it using some sort of regular expression which will operate faster and don't loop through the array?

Comment: You have to loop through array because regex works on string not array.

Comment: hmmm.... so any idea how to make the loop at minimal?

Comment: think about, if your last element contain matching filed means, how you find it out without using loop

Comment: I think you have to break second string also and then get appropriate value from first array.

Comment: @Tareq Just to get an idea: Like how many elements does your array +/- has? (Also start to try something in one direction and I'm sure you will find the way to your solution, either on your own or with this question :)

Comment: @Rizier123 my array has 21000+ records

Answer (score 0):

try below solution:

```
$array = array("6", "66", "67", "68", "69", "697", "698", "699");

$str = '697986546';
//get all matched valuew
$new_arr = array_filter($array, function ($val) use ($str) {
    return (strpos($str, $val) !== false);
});

print_r($new_arr);
if ($new_arr) {
//sort data by string length
    usort($new_arr, function ($a, $b) {
        return strlen($b) - strlen($a);
    });
    print_r($new_arr);

    echo "longest value is - " . $new_arr[0];
}
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 6
    [4] => 69
    [5] => 697
)
Array
(
    [0] => 697
    [1] => 69
    [2] => 6
)
longest value is - 697
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

Just loop through your array and check if the value exists in your string with [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) and if does plus it is longer than the longest subSequence right now you can reassign it, e.g.

```
$longestSubsequence = "";
foreach($array as $v){

    if(strpos($str, $v) !== FALSE && strlen($v) > strlen($longestSubsequence ))
        $longestSubsequence = $v;

}
echo $longestSubsequence;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this solution using substr():

```
<?php
$match = "";
$array = array("6", "66", "67", "68", "69", "697", "698", "699");
$strings = array("69212345", "6209876544", "697986546");
for ($i=0; $i < count($strings); $i++) { //loop to get the $string values
  for ($ii=0; $ii < sizeof($array); $ii++) { //loop to get the $array values
    for ($iii=0; $iii < strlen($strings[$i]); $iii++) { //this loop will increment until the end of the string to compare the array if it matches the substr() of $strings
      if (substr($strings[$i], 0, $iii + 1) == $array[$ii]) {
        $match = $array[$ii];
      }
    }
  }
  echo "for \"" . $strings[$i] . "\" array value \"" . $match . "\" will be selected<br>";
}
?>
```

**Output:**

```
for "69212345" array value "69" will be selected
for "6209876544" array value "6" will be selected
for "697986546" array value "697" will be selected
```

Comment: If the longest subSequence isn't at the start your code doesn't work.